# Потянуть время при загрузки страницы

Tags: html, php

Всем доброго времени суток.

Представим, страничка HTML/PHP... Внутри нее много всякого разного. Требуется в первых строчках страницы (или в первой) написать такую команду, которая бы предотвращала загрузку страницы на указанное кол-во секунд (в моем случае на 2). Есть такое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все предельно просто:

```
sleep(2);
```

А можно использовать буферизацию вывода:

```
ob_start(); //Открываем буфер
//Тут код/данные, которые нужно сначала прогрузить
ob_end_flush(); //Закрываем буфер и отправляем данные клиенту
```

Comment: Спс. Узнал больше чем хотел.